# Netflix on Firefox 50/51/51.0b1 Ubuntu trusty

Tags: 14.04, firefox, 32-bit, netflix

I have updated my `libavcodec`, in version 49 Netflix ran flawlessly using a user agent switcher.  Now, after updating to 50, Netflix gives me error codes `F7363-1260` and `M7363-1260`.

Does anyone know of a way of getting Netflix working again on this 32-bit system?

Update: I have been digging around my system and found `widevine`, the version is `widevine 1.4.8.903` also has updated and that even downgrading to a working version of Firefox still does not work with Netflix.

widevine version:`widevine 1.4.8.903`
Firefox versions: `49.0, 49.02, 50, 51.0b1`

Update 2: I have tried fresh installs of `Firefox` with no luck i have removed all `libav` associated files as well with no luck i have tried disabling all my plugins with no luck. tried `Vivaldi` as well again no luck with `vivaldi` netflix complains of outdated components.
I'm really at a loss as how to fix what was working i have no options to upgrade my hardware to support `64bit`. I'm lucky to have the `32bit` hardware in the first place.

thus far I've tried everything you can find on ask Ubuntu as well as everything i could personally find on google bing and duck duck go i know i haven't tried everything in the world why i asked here.

Comment: try to empty FF cache ?

Comment: yes i have tried that as well.  i did notice the widevine provided by google also updated the day my netflix stopped. 

thank you david for the edit.

Comment: It works fine on Chrome and Xubuntu 16.04:  ok  chrome is only 64 bit so you need reinstall  a 64 bit Linux  (or find some old 32 bit chrome ?)

Comment: this machine is 32bit only there is no way this machine can run 64bit os.
otherwise i'd just use chrome for chrome is my preferred browser.

Comment: about archived chrome 32 bit :  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267587/where-to-download-chrome-32bit-since-it-has-been-discontinued-by-google

Comment: I have updated my os to 16.04 it still didn't work. so i did a fresh install of 16.10 and still doesn't work.